# Some content files are not including in MSI package in Windows installer

Tags: .net, wix, installation, windows-installer

@All,
I am trying to deploy my .Net web application using MSI Windows installer file. 
I am able to create MSI package file and also install it on the server. 
But I observed some content files are missing. It is not included in the package itself.
Please let me know if someone already resolved such issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer was not including some content file because those content files(.JS) files are generated after compiling .TS typescript files. 
One has to compile .TS file separately before building the main project, then only installer includes all the content files.